# install cakephp with other website

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I have one web server. I would like run 2 website on this server. 1 website with SPIP (already running good) and 1 website with cakephp (problem with it).

> SPIP => /var/www/vitrine/
>
> cakephp => /var/www/client/

The cakephp website is accessible by `client.<url>.eu` but when i go to this address, i have a 404 error. Can you say me why ?

Here my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

  DocumentRoot /var/www/vitrine
  ServerName <url>.eu
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/vitrine>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn

  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

  DocumentRoot /var/www/client/app/webroot
  ServerName client.<url>.eu
  <Directory /var/www/client>
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Here the /var/www/client/app/.htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here the /var/www/client/app/webroot/.htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Please use real paths/names when asking questions, don't anonimize things. It only makes the problem more complex to solve. For example, you are talking about `/var/www/metier` at the top of your questions, but have `/var/www/client` in your configs. That is way too confusing! It could be your problem or it could be anonimized, but there is no way for us to tell. Please paste your *real* paths and configs!

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake. The config file is correct, it is /var/www/client.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file at /var/www/client with following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

It works for me that way